# Import from excel file a current range of cells to MySql using Python

Tags: python, mysql, excel, import

My Project involves
1) Import data from excel file

```
path="...\dataexample.xls"
databook=xlrd.open_workbook(path)
mydatasheet=databook.sheet_by_index(0)
```

2) Connect to a localhost database

```
database = MySQLdb.connect (host=myhost, user = myuser, passwd = mypasswd, db = dbname)
```

3) Import a current range of cell of cells to the database
`My`. `dataexample.xls` has 12 rows and 122 cols and for my INSERT QUERY I need only A3:J12 cells
After some search I'am in the point where:

- Preparation for the query and

  `cursor = database.cursor()
  query = """INSERT INTO agiosathanasios(record,Stn_Code,Raw_Dist,Snow,Snow_corr,Smp,Raw_Dist_QC,Snow_final,Snow_final_pos) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""`
- Collect the correct cells for the query

  ```
  for row in range(3,12):
  values=[]
  for col in range(0,10):
      values.append(mydatasheet.cell(row,col).value)
  print values
  ```

I was trying to put after values.append the following code `database, cursor.execute(query,values)`so I can import the value I want.

But... it does work...

how can I fix this? How can I put the current values to my query ?

Comment: What exactly does not work? This code produce errors?

Comment: I am using PyScripter. If I run it with for row in range(3,12):
    values=[]
    for col in range(0,10):
        values.append(mydatasheet.cell(row,col).value)
    cursor.execute(query,values)
, it opens cursor.py and i have TypeError

Comment: Message File Name Line Position 
Traceback    
    <module> C:\Users\ANASTASIADIS STAVROS\Desktop\The Documents\PythonWork\DataManagement.py 50  
    execute C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py 184  
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: ndpu, after fixing my items, i have new error: Message File Name Line Position 
Traceback    
    <module> C:\Users\ANASTASIADIS STAVROS\Desktop\The Documents\PythonWork\DataManagement.py 51  
    execute C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py 202  
    defaulterrorhandler C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py 36  
"OperationalError: (1136, ""Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"")"

Comment: I have check it several times. My values is a list with float numbers. Its possible that the cursor.execute works with tuples structure only? .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, according to tracebacks, you provide not all parameters to your query or there is some problem with converting values to string (None in values). Check values before calling cursor.execute!

Try to convert to string values from excel:

```
values.append(str(mydatasheet.cell(row,col).value))
```